# Blank page with 500.0 response for index.php when loging it

Tags: mysql, php, iis, 500-error

The page will work normally but as soon as you press login or sign-up, goes to a blank page and in element inspect you can see a 500 response from the server
I've tried many different login/sign-up pages and all comes back to this error, I've enabled logging, checked for coding errors.
In the IIS log, you get this message;

`POST /test2/ - 80 - ::1 (`*`Blah, just browser info`*`) http://localhost/test2/ 500 0 0 4033`

So error 500.0

All file permissions are set correctly and as i said before the file works normally until you try to login

Information, Tell me if you need more

Windows Server 2022 Standard (Build 20348)

IIS 10

MySQL v8.0 + shell and workbench

PHP v8.0

Comment: Increase the log level if necessary. The log is the only thing that can help you.

Comment: Enable FRT to see more about such 500.0 errors, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis In most cases, it should be triggered by unhandled exceptions in your web app.

Comment: @LexLi
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName FastCgiModule 

Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 

HttpStatus 500 

HttpReason Internal Server Error 

HttpSubStatus 0 

ErrorCode The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)

Comment: If FRT gave you that log entry, then you have to review the actual PHP page and debug into the unhandled exceptions (500.0 comes from there, not any IIS components). BTW, you should host PHP web apps on a Linux machine (or VM), or WSL on Windows Server. Microsoft no longer supports PHP 8 on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the information, i was unaware of dropped support for PHP, Since on of my machines running windows server supports Hyper-virtualization and i already have VMware configured, at the time of sending this im setting up a linux VM for web hosting